# how to get stream link from live video

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, flash

how can I get direct stream link of live videos and play in VLC player. for example how should I get direct link of this page :

http://www.sportingvideo.org/20161005/vv57f4dce9e46e83.75702779-1448498.html

Comment: Are you asking for the URL of the video within a web page? Either view the source or use a tool like Fiddler to see what requests to URLs are being made by the page as it runs.

Comment: I've used firebug for finding the video link but I can't find any video link. I can get video link in some other websites, but this website seems so complicated to find the video link.